# Updating dataframe with array ouput

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to copy results from an array to dataframe from a for loop.  However, each time I try this, the last value of the loop is updated in the dataframe:

```
counter = 0
sample = [1,2,5,10,15,20,30,60,120,180,240,300,360,420,480,540,600]
columns = ['1','2','5','10','15','20','30','60','120','180','240','300','360','420','480','540','600']

index = df.set_index([df.index])
resultsDf = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
resultsDf = pd.DataFrame()
resultsDf.set_index([resultsDf.index])

results = []
for index, rowEntry in TradesGTC.iterrows():#Entry of Trade
    entryVolume = rowEntry[26]
    entryPrice = rowEntry[28]
    ccyPair = rowEntry[12][0:6]    
    entryTime = rowEntry['DateTime']
    for data in sample:        
        exitTime = entryTime + dt.timedelta(seconds = data)
        f = MD.between_time(entryTime,exitTime)
        buy = entryVolume > 0
        sell = entryVolume < 0
        if buy == True:
            maxBidinTimeFrame = f['bid'].max()            
            profit = (maxBidinTimeFrame - entryPrice) * entryVolume
            results.append(profit)
        if sell == True:
            minAskinTimeFrame = f['offer'].min()
            profit = (entryPrice - minAskinTimeFrame) * entryVolume
            results.append(profit)
        resultsDf.append(results)
```

The output which is returned is:

```
resultsDf

1   2   5   10  15  20  30  60  120 180 240 300 360 420 480 540 600
```

I expect to have a dataframe with column headers
    1 2 5 10.... 600
and the results listed in each column going down so..

```
1 2 3 5 10....600
100 200 100...-50 
.
.
```

Appreciate all help 
Thanks

Comment: Right away I see that you overwrite `df` at the bottom of your loop instead of appending new columns. Also, is the formatting of your question right? Nothing is indented after your first `for` loop (the one for `TradesGTC`).

Comment: I'm curious why `resultsDf ` is `resultsDf = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)` then immediately after you define it as `resultsDf = pd.DataFrame()`.

Comment: Guys thanks for looking
@chrisaycock Thanks the formatting was because of copy past to stackoverflow.

I have updated the question with appending the results.  But I know get the column heading but none of the results.

Comment: @Jarad I have removed the line you mentioned.  I have updated the example.

Comment: What is the initial `df` in the line `index = df.set_index([df.index])`?

Comment: Also, what is `TradesGTC` supposed to be? Please, make sure your example is reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all, but the missing piece in the puzzle..

```
resultsDf = resultsDf.append(pd.DataFrame(data = results), ignore_index=True)
```